# SQL query for table with multiple keys?

Tags: sql

I am sorry if this seems too easy but I was asked this question and I couldn't answer even after preparing SQL thoroughly :(. Can someone answer this?

There's a table - Seller id, product id, warehouse id, quantity of products at each warehouse for each product as per each seller.

We have to list the Product Ids with Seller Id who has highest number of products for that product and the total number of units he has for that product.

I think I got confused because there were 3 keys in the table.

Comment: I'm wondering what you mean by this --> "even after preparing SQL thoroughly"  -- it sounds like something I should do if I knew what it was.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output

Comment: Also, SQL is a standard. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear which DBMS you are using currently. The below should work if your DBMS support window functions.

You can find count of rows for each product and seller, rank each seller within each product using window function `rank` and then use filter to get only top ranked sellers in each product along with count of units.

```
select
    product_id,
    seller_id,
    no_of_products
from (
    select 
        product_id,
        seller_id,
        count(*) no_of_products,
        rank() over (partition by product_id order by count(*) desc) rnk
    from your_table
    group by 
        product_id,
        seller_id
) t where rnk = 1;
```

If window functions are not supported, you can use correlated query to achieve the same effect:

```
select
    product_id,
    seller_id,
    count(*) no_of_products
from your_table a
group by
    product_id,
    seller_id
having count(*) = (
    select max(cnt)
    from (
        select count(*) cnt
        from your_table b
        where b.product_id = a.product_id
        group by seller_id
    ) t
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why having id columns would mess you up... group by the right columns, sum up the totals and just return the first row:

```
select *
from (
  select sellerid, productid, sum(quantity) as total_sold
  from theres_a_table
  group by sellerid, productid
) x
order by total_sold desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Answer (score 0):

If I do not think about optimization, straight forward answer is like this

```
select *
from
(
select seller_id, product_id, sum(product_qty) as seller_prod_qty
from your_table
group by seller_id, product_id
) spqo
inner join 
(
 select product_id, max(seller_prod_qty) as max_prod_qty
 from
 (
  select seller_id, product_id, sum(product_qty) as seller_prod_qty
  from your_table
  group by seller_id, product_id
 ) spqi
 group by product_id
) pmaxq
on spqo.product_id = pmaxq.product_id
and spqo.seller_prod_qty = pmaxq.max_prod_qty
```

both spqi (inner) and sqpo (outer) give you seller, product, sum of quantity across warehouses. pmaxq gives you max of each product again across warehouses, and then final inner join picks up sum of quantities if seller has highest (max) of the product (could be multiple sellers with the same quantity). I think this is the answer you are looking for. However, I'm sure query can be improved, since what I'm posting is the "conceptual" one :)